# OpenLayers: transform GPS coordinates to EPSG:25832

Tags: openlayers

I want to get GPS coordinates with a button click and change them into the EPSG:25832 format to center my map. Here is what I have coded so far:

```
jQuery('#btnGPS').click(function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
  } else {
    alert("Not Supported!");
  }
});

function success(position) {
  alert(position.coords.longitude + ',' + position.coords.latitude);
  var SRS_MAP = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:25832"); 
  var SRS_LONLAT = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"); 
  var center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(position.coords.longitude,position.coords.latitude); 
  var test = center.transform(SRS_LONLAT,SRS_MAP); 
  alert(test);
}
```

Finally my Map Object:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map',{
      controls: [
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()
                ],
                projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:25832"),
                displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                units: 'm',
                maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(356570.500,5442150.416,383807.687,5462691.920),
                maxResolution: 'auto',
                numZoomLevels: 8
            });
```

I always get the same coordinates back, with no transformation at all. Position Object with lon and lat are working fine, but I cannot get the OpenLayers transform function to work properly. I am using the newest standard OpenLayers.

I am quite new to OpenLayers so please be very specific about the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proj4js. Here's the link with instructions for OpenLayers: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Documentation/Dev/proj4js.
Make sure to add the definition for EPSG:25832 as instructed.